# sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (mysql.connector.errors.OperationalError) MySQL Connection not available

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

For some reason I am getting the disconnect error message with the database. I am using Flask, Python and SQLAlchemy and the app is running on pythonanywhere.com
I've been through similar questions and can't find a solution to the problem.
Specifically I have app.config["SQLALCHEMY_POOL_RECYCLE"] = 299 as the recommended setting. However in the following link https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/UsingSQLAlchemywithMySQL/ I found in pythonanywhere the recommendation says that pool recycle should have a value of 280.

I am using Flask-SQLAlchemy==3.0.5 and sqlalchemy version '2,0,19'

```
Python 3.10.5 (main, Jul 22 2022, 17:09:35) [GCC 9.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sqlalchemy
>>> sqlalchemy.__version__
'2.0.19'
>>>
```

My configuration is:

```
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = "mysql+mysqlconnector://{username}:{password}@{hostname}/{databasename}".format(
    username=DATABASE_USERNAME,
    password=DATABASE_PASSWORD,
    hostname=DATABASE_HOST_NAME,
    databasename=DATABASE_NAME
)

app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_POOL_RECYCLE"] = 280
```

The documentation at the following link https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/UsingSQLAlchemywithMySQL/ on pythonanywhere states the following "If you're using the Flask-SQLAlchemy plugin, then for recent versions you configure it like this:

```
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_ENGINE_OPTIONS'] = {'pool_recycle' : 280}
db.init_app(app)
```

"

My question is:
I should replace

```
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_POOL_RECYCLE"] = 280
```

with

```
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_ENGINE_OPTIONS'] = {'pool_recycle' : 280}
```

Thanks.

Comment: It is already mentioned in the documentation. why do you aks here?

Comment: Testing now:     app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = os.getenv("SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI")
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_ENGINE_OPTIONS'] = {'pool_recycle': 280}

Answer (score 0):

Solution found: Implement the new format recommended by the link https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/UsingSQLAlchemywithMySQL/ and leave the web application running for 7 minutes with no screen activity. The result is satisfactory. The application did not detect detection of loss of connection with the MySQL database. The recommendation to follow is to keep track of the Flask-SQLAlchemy version and correctly apply the new format app.config['SQLALCHEMY_ENGINE_OPTIONS'] = {'pool_recycle' : 280} to solve the case of lost connection with MySQL.